# Create a "Tip View" in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Suppose I have a UIView that has some buttons and stuff, and I want to help the user understand some features of it by showing some small pop ups. ( For example, I would write in a pop up: "Tip: This is how you can access the database").
It's like doing a small tutorial for a new user the first time he downloads the app.
I know there is the UIPopUpViewController for iPad. 
I was wondering if there was a similar thing for iPhone, something that will help me achieve this goal.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this git.

https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover